# how to remove numbering in list using word tokenize function in python ? I am getting the output but i need without numbers

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nltk

I dont need the list numbers (i.e.) 0,1 etc. I need to print elements 
  without numbering

```
    import pandas as pd
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    import csv
    # define punctuation
    my_str=pd.read_csv("ef.csv")
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~...'''
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(str(my_str))
    #mystr=str(my_str)
    # remove punctuation from the string
    no_punct = [char for char in word_tokens if not char in punctuations]
    no_punct=[]
    for char in word_tokens:
      if char not in punctuations:
          #no_punct = no_punct + char
           no_punct.append(char)
```

how to remove numbering in list using word tokenize function in python ? I am getting the output but i need without numbers

Comment: Could you provide some example input and output?

Comment: I am getting the output as

Comment: ['Raghavan', 'teaching', 'is', 'excellent', '0', 'Sankar', 'is', 'good', 'at', 'teaching', '1', 'Darwin', 'is', 'extraordinary', 'in', 'teaching']

Comment: But I need without 0 and 1 in the above code

Comment: Input file is "Raghavan @ teaching is & excellent
Sankar ( is good at teaching.
Darwin * is extraordinary in teaching
"

Comment: Sorry for the delay, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and try and give us some more context to work with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, this can be done using simple python...

```
sentence=['Raghavan', 'teaching', 'is', 'excellent', '0', 'Sankar', 'is', 'good', 'at', 'teaching', '1', 'Darwin', 'is', 'extraordinary', 'in', 'teaching']
for i in sentence:
    try:
        if str(int(float(i))).isnumeric():
            sentence.remove(i)
    except:
        pass
print(sentence)
# output - ['Raghavan', 'teaching', 'is', 'excellent', 'Sankar', 'is', 'good', 'at', 'teaching', 'Darwin', 'is', 'extraordinary', 'in', 'teaching']
```

Comment: Thank u got the answer